# Static methods in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

After call static method from another controller, it showing error message

```
$shipprice = CartController::calcshipping();

Error: 
    Using $this when not in object context
```

Comment: this means that the static function you are calling contain a reference to $this (static functions should never contain a call to $this)

Answer (score 4):

You don't call controllers from other controllers - ever.

You either put your code into components or models. This way you can share the functionality between different controllers without such hacks as above.

And then there is also no need to do any static stuff here.
It can simply be a normal object call.

```
$this->MyComponent->calc();
```

or

```
$this->MyModel->calc();
```

etc